# Slick carousel won't initiate

Tags: jquery, slick.js

There must be a simple answer to this, but I can't get this slick carousel to work, even though I've stripped it down to the bare minimum:

https://jsfiddle.net/LNMSchneiderman/4vf4hfy2/1/

Attached files:

```
slick-1.6.0/slick/slick.css
slick-1.6.0/slick/slick-theme.css
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick-1.6.0/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

html:

```
<div class="ss_mobile" id="ss_mobile_westend">
                <div><img src="img/westend/mobile/20160317dsOhioRiverBrWestEndBrMag08_forweb.jpg" /></div>
                <div><img src="img/westend/mobile/20160317dsOhioRiverBrWestEndBrMag03_forweb.jpg" /></div>
                <div><img src="img/westend/mobile/20160317dsOhioRiverBrWestEndBrMag02_forweb.jpg" /></div>
            </div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#ss_mobile_westend').slick({

  });
});
```

I'm pulling my hair out over this. Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think your external resources has the wrong path or something.
I tried this and it worked. https://jsfiddle.net/SimplyFox/54fd1m18/

Add the external resources in the following order:

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js
```

HTML
    
            [image]
<sub>(source: [post-gazette.com](http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/bridges/ohio/img/westend/mobile/20160317dsOhioRiverBrWestEndBrMag08_forweb.jpg))</sub>
            [image]
<sub>(source: [post-gazette.com](http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/bridges/ohio/img/westend/mobile/20160317dsOhioRiverBrWestEndBrMag03_forweb.jpg))</sub>
            [image]
<sub>(source: [post-gazette.com](http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/bridges/ohio/img/westend/mobile/20160317dsOhioRiverBrWestEndBrMag02_forweb.jpg))</sub>

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ss_mobile').slick();
});
```

Comment: The images are just stacking up for me, not going into a slideshow. Can you take a look? http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/bridges/ohio/test.html

Comment: From what I see, it works. I added 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ss_mobile').slick();
});
on your link and the carousel appeared. So check for typos or the paths that you have included.

Comment: It already had $(document).ready(function(){ $('.ss_mobile').slick(); }); in the head. Why didn't that work?

Comment: @LauraNMS I think I found your problem. get rid of the type="jquery/jquery" in the<script> in <head> where you were putting in there originally. It should work.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I still can't get this test carousel working, but strangely, the carousels on my actual page are working. The problem appears to be that I put display:none on the wrapper around the slideshow, then faded the slideshow in. Somehow that wasn't enough for the carousel. I have to say display:block for the wrapper. Thank you again!